# NodeJs HTTP Post call, how to use it as an API for AngularJs which uses $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, azure

I have a NodeJS file which calls POST and get data from Azure. I want to convert it into API which can be used by AngularJS $http.

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');
function getPred() {
    var data = {
        "Inputs": {
    "input1":
    {
        "ColumnNames": ["Age", "Gender", "Chest Pain Type", "Resting BP", "Serum Cholestrol", "Fasting Blood Pressure", "ECG", "Max Heart Rate", "ST Depression"],
      "Values": [ [ "20", "1", "4", "130", "322", "0", "2", "109", "0" ] ]
    },        },
"GlobalParameters": {
}
};

var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {
host: 'ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net',
port: 443,
path: '/workspaces/8671b8e183d84ca58badf842d26ccdc6/services/8cde3573ca814c89967265a80c84cbd9/execute?api-version=2.0',
method: 'POST',
headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':'Bearer APIKEY'}
};

var reqPost = https.request(options, function (res) {

    res.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log("Output")
    process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
reqPost.write(dataString);
reqPost.end();
reqPost.on('error', function(e){
console.error(e);
});
}
http.createServer().listen(8050);
console.log("Server is now running on port 8050");
getPred();
```

In general, how can I convert this post into an API call where i can use to post it using AngularJS.

my routing would be:

```
app.post('/api/user/insertUser/',userCtrl.Signup);
```

In angularJS:

```
$http.post('/api/user/insertUser', signup_data).then(function(response){
    .....
});
```

I would pass the data in signup_data and in the response, I would get the data I need.

Is there any way where I can convert the above POST request so that I can use it through AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) and [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to convert your POST request into an express route.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/user/insertUser', function (request, response) {


    var data = request.signup_data;

    var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var options = {
        host: 'ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net',
        port: 443,
        path: '/workspaces/8671b8e183d84ca58badf842d26ccdc6/services/8cde3573ca814c89967265a80c84cbd9/execute?api-version=2.0',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':'Bearer APIKEY'}
    };

    var reqPost = https.request(options, function (res) {

        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(d) {
            console.log("Output")
            body += d;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            response.json(body);
        });
    });

    reqPost.on('error', function(e){
        console.error(e);
    });

    reqPost.write(dataString);
    reqPost.end();

})

app.listen(8050, function () {
    console.log("Server is now running on port 8050");
})
```